# With the given the condition, prove that $\,\,x^4+ y^4 \propto x^3y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck with the following problem that says :

If $x^2+5y^2 \displaystyle \propto 3xy$, then prove that $\,\,x^4+ y^4 \propto x^3y$

Can someone help me out with the aforementioned problem? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is your definition of $\propto$?  It can't be strictly proportional as if $x$ or $y$ is zero the right side is $0$ while the left is not.

Comment: There is need for more context, but $y$ being a constant multiple of $x$ would follow from the condition, whence the conclusion is evident.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+5y^2 \displaystyle \propto 3xy \\ \implies x^2+y^2=k. 3xy\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{where k is constant of variation} \\ \implies \frac{x^2}{y^2}+5 \frac{y^2}{y^2}=k . \frac{3xy}{y^2} \\ \implies \left(\frac {x}{y}\right )^2-3k.\frac{x}{y}+5=0 \\ \implies \frac{x}{y}=\frac{3k \pm \sqrt{(3k)^2-4 \times 1 \times 5}}{2}=m \,\,\text{where m is constant of variation} \\ \implies x =my$$

Now, $$\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^3y}=\frac{(my)^4+y^4}{(my)^3y}=\cdots=\frac{m^4+1}{m^3}=k_1$$
Hence,  $\,\,x^4+ y^4 \propto x^3y$